# Is there some short cut form of writing: .map { $0 }

Tags: swift, closures, swift5

```
.map { $0 }
```

I feel like it should be possible to write as just:

```
.map()
```

or something

Or real world example:

```
let values = Dict<String: [Int]>(some data here).values.flatMap { $0 }
```

Comment: At the start you are talking `map { $0 }`, but by the end of your question you are talking about `flatMap { $0 }`? Which method are you asking about?

Comment: @Sweeper The question is more about closure in general than about specific method. If there is solution for .map then the same solution should work for .flatMap also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can actually use flatMap and pass value as the keypath:

```
let dict: [String: [Int]] = ["a": [1,2,3]]
let values = dict.flatMap(\.value)   // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ow, that's a good one. Let's wait a little bit for any other solutions but looks like this one will be an accepted answer. Anyways thank you :)

Comment: Why doesn't "dict.values.flatMap(\.self)" compile? Isn't it the same approach? Error: "Key path value type '_' cannot be converted to contextual type 'Dictionary<String, [Int]>.Values.Element' (aka 'Array<Int>')"

Comment: Funny that I have already tried that syntax as well before realizing how to write it. It is about how the language was designed. The syntax above it is only supported in Swift 5.2 and above.https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md

Comment: @Roman If you would like to implement your own flatMap method that takes a keyPath `extension Sequence {` `func flatMap<T>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [Element.Element] where Element: Collection {` `flatMap { $0 }` `}`
`}`

Comment: The map equivalent `extension Sequence {` `func map<T>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> [Element] {` `map { $0 }` `}` `}` and the compactMap `extension Sequence {` `func compactMap<T>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T?>) -> [T] where Element == Optional<T> {` `compactMap { $0 }` `}` `}`