# Swift - Reducing a Dictionary of Arrays to a single array of same type using map/reduce/flatmap

Tags: swift, dictionary, reduce, flatmap

Given an input like so:

```
let m = ["one": ["1","2","3"],
         "two":["4","5"]
    ]
```

how can I use map/reduce to produce the output like:

```
["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

I'm not very swifty, and trying to learn it but I cant seem to figure out an efficient way to do this simple operation. My verbose approach would be like so:

```
var d = [String]()

for (key, value) in m {
    value.forEach { (s) in
        d.append(s)
    }
}
print(d)
```

I'm sure this can be a 1 liner, could someone assist?

Comment: You're going to run into a big issue here: dictionaries aren't ordered.

Comment: ...but if this is not an issue for you, your one-liner would be `m.values.flatMap { $0 }`

Comment: Equivalently: `Array(m.values.joined())`

Comment: Thanks, order was not important in my case. Alexanders answer was exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a single `flatMap`:

```
let result = dict.flatMap { _, values in values }
```

Comment: Or `dict.flatMap { $1 }`

Comment: @MartinR I prefer `dict.flatMap(\.value)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63515834/2303865

Comment: Swift is like Perl: [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)